# (EF6) How can I specify a different ConnectionString to be used with Automatic Migrations?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I want to have two different SQL connections. One will leverage code-first automatic migrations to keep the database schema up-to-date. The other will do the typical website day-to-day.

I have both connection strings in my Web.config (one named "Migrator" and the other named "Agent").

How can I accomplish this?

Right now the schema is updated on the first read or write to the database, so I'm unsure where I can even set this...

Comment: I prefer you can set this in default page load.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else was wondering the same thing, the way I ended up doing this was:

```
static MyDbContext()
{
    Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MyDbContext, MyProgram.Migrations.Configuration>("Migrator"));
}

public MyDbContext() : base("Agent")
{
}
```

In this way whenever "MyDbContext" is first initialized or accessed it initializes my database using the "Migrator" connection string.